# How to get the multiple http request results in my example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a http request and place the returned result into my array.

I have something like

Ctrl

```
for (var i=0; i < numOfProduct.length; i++) {
   productFactory.makeRequest(numOfProduct[i].id)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log(i)
                        //always output 10 which is my numOfProduct.length

                        numOfProduct[i].push({detail: data}); 
                        //i got Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error
                    })
                $scope.numOfProduct = numOfProduct;
}
```

productFactory

```
service.makeRequest = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/product/get' + id);
}

return service;
```

My goal is to push a http request result into each of numOfProduct element as an object. However, I can't seem to do that with the http request codes I have. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: i'm not sure but i guess it is due to the ajax call of async. In then function assign $scope.numOfProduct = numOfProduct;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues with the above:

1 is a common callback issue where you're binding a reference to `i` but not to the value of `i`. So, by the time your callback gets called, the loop will have finished and `i` will be 10 in all of the callbacks that you bound.

One way to fix this is to force evaluation of `i` through a function call:

```
function makeCallback(productId) {
 productFactory.makeRequest(productId)
                    .then(function(data) {
                        console.log(i)
                        return ({detail: data}); 
                    });
}
```

The second issue is that you are calling `.push` on a specific value in the array `numOfProduct` instead of an actual array. (Unless that specific value is an array, which i'm assuming it isn't since you are calling `.id` on the value)

Try this instead:

```
function makeCallback(productId) {
     productFactory.makeRequest(productId)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            console.log(i)
                            return ({detail: data}); 
                        })
}
var array = [];
for (var i=0; i < numOfProduct.length; i++) {    
    array.push(makeCallback(numOfProduct[i].id));
}
$scope.numOfProduct = array;
```

If each loop is being ran asynchronously then I suggest using the popular [async libary](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async). Let me know if you need any help setting this up.