# How to solve my http request issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have a question about the http request.
Here is my old post.

[How to get the multiple http request results in my example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26705556/how-to-get-the-multiple-http-request-results-in-my-example)

I have modified my codes a bit. Basically I need to make multiple http requests and store them into an `productGroup` array. However, I am getting `undefined` for the returned result.

```
  var buildProduct = function(product) {
        var productGroup = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
            var t = buildProductDetail(product, i)
            productGroup.push(t);
        }
        console.log(productGroup) // I am getting undefined here.
        return productGroup;
    }

var buildProductDetail = function(product, i) {
    var plan = {}
    getProductDetail(product[i].id)
        .then(function(data){
            plan = {detail: data.detail, name:product[i].name}
            console.log(plan) //has data
            return plan;     
        })
}

var getProductDetail = function(id) {
    return $http.get('/api/project/getProduct' + id);
}
```

Comment: `buildProductDetail` doesn't return anything, thus `undefined`.

Comment: I thought return plan; will return the object

Comment: [From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/), `.then` adds handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected, or still in progress. So you need to check if the deferred object has resolved. So you should push the elements in the `.success` callback of your `ajax` request or the `.done` filter for your deferred object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had undefined because your `buildProductDetail` function didn't return anything.

If you want a clean result use the $q api to resolve several promises at the same time.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

I think it should work with something looking like this but I can't test without a plunkr.
Inject $q (native in angularjs, no external dep needed) and then :

```
  var buildProduct = function(product) {
        var productGroup = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < product.length; i++) {
            var t = buildProductDetail(product, i)
            productGroup.push(t);
        }
        return $q.all( productGroup );
    }

var buildProductDetail = function(product, i) {
    var plan = {}
     return getProductDetail(product[i].id) // don't forget the return there
        .then(function(data){
            plan = {detail: data.detail, name:product[i].name}
            console.log(plan) //has data
            return plan;     
        })
}
```